# Using Popen in Python in ssh to Run "ls -lh INPUTS" Bash Commands

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, popen

INPUTS is the variable I gave for the absolute path of a directory of possible input files. I want to check their status before going through my pipeline. So I tried:

```
import subprocess
import argparse

INPUTS = '/home/username/WinterResearch/Inputs'
status = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-lh', INPUTS], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = status.communicate()
status.stdout.close()
```

I have also tried the often used

```
from shlx import split
import subprocess
import argparse

cmd = 'ls -lh INPUTS'
status = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and

```
cmd = "ls -lh 'INPUTS'"
```

I do not receive an error code. The process simply does not output anything to the terminal window. I am not sure why the python script simply skips over this instead of stating there is an error. I do receive an error when I include `close_fds=True` that states int cannot use communicate(). So how can I receive an output from some `ls -lh INPUTS` equivalent using subprocess.Popen()?

Comment: Considering slashes you are on macOS X or some Linux. Then change your INPUT variable to `~/WinterResearch/Inputs` or put there absolute path, which starts with `/Users`... Or check that your intended command executes correctly in terminal.

Comment: I tried the `~/WinterResearch/Inputs` and the error was that there was `"No such file or directory found"`. The `ls -lh /home/username/WinterResearch/Inputs` is fine from terminal.

Comment: `shell=True` is your problem here.

Comment: `os.path.expanduser()` will fix up the `~/WinterResearch/Inputs` string, replacing the `~` with the user's actual home directory (just as a shell would do otherwise).

Comment: BTW, why do you *expect* this code to write anything to a terminal? Your content is being captured into a pipe -- because you asked for it to be -- the output of which is dumped into the variable named `stdout`.

Comment: ...when you say "receive an output", then, do you mean you want the output written to your program's stdout and *not* captured in a variable? Just get rid of the `stdout=` argument, and that'll happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see any output because you're not printing to console stdout — it's saved into a variable (*named "stdout"*). `Popen` is overkill for this task anyway since you aren't piping the command to another. `check_output` should work fine with subprocess for this purpose:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output("ls -lh {0}".format(INPUTS), shell=True)
```

> <sub>**[subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)**(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False,
>   universal_newlines=False)</sub>
>    <sub>Run command with arguments and return its
>   output as a byte string.</sub>

***METHOD WITH LESSER SECURITY RISK:*** ([see warnings plastered throughout this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects))

> <sub>**EDIT**: Using `communicate()` can avoid the potential
>   `shell=True` security risk:</sub>

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-lh", INPUTS]).communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

Comment: If your directory name contains a space, this will behave very badly. If it contains `$(rm -rf ~)` or `; rm -rf ~`, even worse. Far safer to remove the `shell=True` and keep the OP's original code otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! This worked when I put it in a print() statement.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I've included an alternative method which doesn't use the `shell` argument at all, so take a look. The OP used `shell=True` as well; I'm not sure why `ls -lh` would suddenly turn into `rm -rf ~`. Regardless of how that might happen, the documentation highlights the potential risk numerous times; let me know if the new method I added meets your approval, thanks!

Comment: @l'L'l, to explain *"why `ls -lh` would suddenly turn into `rm -rf ~`"*, keep in mind that on POSIX-y platforms `shell=True` works by prepending `['sh', '-c']` to the argument list. If `INPUTS='~/WinterResearch/inbox/$(rm -rf ~)'`, then you get `['sh', '-c', 'ls -lh ~/WinterResearch/inbox/$(rm -rf ~)']`. Similarly, if `INPUTS='; rm -rf ~'`, you'd get `['sh', '-c', 'ls -lh; rm -rf ~']`. Clear? That said, this is indeed much improved as-edited.

Answer (score 0):

From your first snippet:

```
stdout = status.communicate()
status.stdout.close()
```

Nothing is being printed here. You may need to change it to the following (or your preferred form/format)

```
stdout = status.communicate()
print stdout
status.stdout.close()
```

Comment: This printed out all of the relative file paths of the parent directory, WinterResearch.